# Store tweets with quotes in a SQLite3 database

Tags: python, twitter, sqlite

I am loading the tweets from the web using json.

```
import urllib2, json, sqlite3
wFD = urllib2.urlopen('http://rasinsrv07.cstcis.cti.depaul.edu/CSC455/Twitter_2013_11_12.txt')
blankLines = 0
goodLines = 0
numLines = 10000
while numLines > 0:
    line = wFD.readline()
    numLines = numLines - 1
    try:    
         tweets.append(json.loads(line))
         goodLines = goodLines+1
    except:
        blankLines = blankLines + 1
blankLines
goodLines
```

I have to check the length of the whole tweet and then store it as one big entry in a table in database using SQLite3.

```
SingleTable = """Create table SingleTable
            (tweet varchar(8038)
            );"""
c.execute("drop table if exists SingleTable")            
c.execute(SingleTable)

len_strTwt = 0
for tweet in tweets:
    str_tweet = str(tweet)
    c.execute("insert into SingleTable values (?)", (str_tweet))
    if len_strTwt < len(str_tweet):
        len_strTwt = len(str_tweet)
len_strTwt
```

When I tried storing it, I was not able to do it because of so many double and single quotes. I do not know how to use the excape symbol here to be able to store it in database. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an additional comma to tell Python that you want a tuple:

```
c.execute("insert into SingleTable values (?)", (str_tweet,))
```

Without the comma, you get a plain string, which will be interpreted by `execute` as a sequence of characters, i.e., each character will be one parameter value.

Please note that SQLite does not check the length of columns by default.